# How thick does the impermeable layer need to be when grading a yard?

Tags: drainage, backyard, grading, soil

I'm grading my yard and have found a deep layer of sand (at least 2 ft) extending out about 10ft. Perhaps the sub base for a patio? I understand I need an impermeable layer to ensure rain runs away from the house rather than drains downwards. I plan to use regular, fairly dense soil from elsewhere in the yard. How thick does that need to be to be effective?

Comment: I question whether you need to make an impermeable cap on this sand layer. Is this a consensus opinion of experts?

Comment: From what I've seen, the impermeable layer helps direct runoff away from the house, rather than letting it seep down by the foundation.

Comment: This idea is plausible, but is it true?  Is this necessary and is it effective? Does it have unwanted effects? The more prevalent idea is to use drains to conduct water from the roof away from foundation and to have surface collection of standing water which is likewise conducted away. The ultimate is the "French drain" which can collect groundwater and conduct it away.  Before you go to the trouble of moving soil around in the yard I think you should consult experts in effects of soil types on water ingress in full basement foundations.

Comment: Gutters is important to take away water landing on the roof. Based on fairly in depth internet research, grading a yard to move water away from a foundation is consistently recommended on legitimate websites. A French drain is also advisable to deal with any water that arrives at the foundation--I have one. I was hoping to find some experts on this site, but maybe this isn't the right forum.